# How do I fix a boolean/bisected surface edge?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, faces

I am trying to slice up my models using the Boolean modifier.

After applying the modifier on my smooth mesh, I get the expected result, a flat dissection to separate my mesh into two.

The problem lies in how I can resolve the visual "jaggered" edge that separates my (smooth) mesh exterior from the flat dissection face.

[image: Artifacts following the boolean operation on a smooth mesh]

Is it possible to achieve a smooth-to-flat variation without this artifact?

I tried to alter a mixture of the two but end up with artifacts, or unwanted blocky flat mesh faces around the dissection edge of my mesh.

[image: Unwanted flat faces around the edge of my dissected mesh]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an *Edge Split* modifier to your mesh, or turn on *Auto Smooth* in the *Object Data* tab of the *Properties Window*

Also check for duplicate geometry in edit mode with the *Remove Doubles* operator.

Comment: Thank you, _Edge Split_ worked a treat! There is the rare little artifact here and there (even after adjusting the Edge Angle) but this appears to be mesh based, not smoothing