# How to clear ngons created in the mesh

Tags: modifiers

I have a simple mesh and when i add the boolean modifier and solidify modifier ngons are created how to clean this ngons and make a clean mesh. In my blend file as you can seen auto smooth is on and i have smooth shading also. Any suggestion

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those couldn't possibly be ngons because the *Boolean* Modifier does not understand faces other than triangles or quads nor does it support creating them. Those are most definitely triangles and resulting shading artifacts, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/applied-boolean-modifier-leaving-shading-artifacts-with-flat-shading or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70575/how-do-i-fix-a-boolean-bisected-surface-edge/70583#70583

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a boolean/bisected surface edge?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70575/how-do-i-fix-a-boolean-bisected-surface-edge)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos in my blend file attach smooth shading and auto smooth option is on still having same result

Comment: That is the result of bad topology from Boolean operaitons combined with uneven vertex densities of the two objects. Try increasing vertex count on the cone object