# Fixing jagged knife project circle

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

I'm trying to think of ways to fix a circular shape that I projected onto a half sphere and I can't seem to be able to fix it using circle tools or modifiers.  If you look closely you can see the faces are uneven.  Is there a way to fix this, and if not, how can I fill the sphere again in the problem area without having to start all over again?

Here's the problem:

[image]

[image]

Here are the modifiers:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I may a found a solution...it's tedious, but seems to be smoothing things out.  If anyone finds an easier workaround, that would still be welcome :)

Basically, I find the problem areas like this:

[image]

Go into edit mode and dissolve (not delete) the edges causing the distortions like this:

[image]

It's not perfect, but it would look like this:

[image]

**NOTE:** It's important to note that removing doubles helps, but doesn't necessarily get rid of these problems, hence why I had to manually dissolve the edges.

Comment: What is the vertex group "Group.001" that is being used for your Cast modifier?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70575/how-do-i-fix-a-boolean-bisected-surface-edge

Comment: @risingfall it's all the faces of the head until it gets to the grey ring near the bottom of BB8's head.  When I applied the cast to the whole head, it deformed the bottom severely.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yes I tried the edge split modifier (I should have mentioned that) and all it did was make the ripples and distortions even more pronounced.  The auto smooth in data didn't have any effect unfortunately.

Comment: @lakerice yes I think you've hit upon one of the reasons ngons usually should be avoided, especially when using a modifier like a subsurf

Comment: @risingfall agreed.  It's strange knife project doesn't work more predictably with circles.  At least in my experience, even a heavily subdivided circle can make more primitive looking cuts.