# Cannot smooth without trouble on my mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm working on my mesh which looks like this : 
[image]

As you can see the surface is not smoothed. Then I apply the smooth option and it gives me this result : 
[image]

It is the third times I start again this mesh... I cannot understand how to apply the boolean modifier without getting in troubles.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please show a screenshot of your mesh, it must be bad, or share your file

Comment: Use the bevel or the edge split modifier.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70575/how-do-i-fix-a-boolean-bisected-surface-edge

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helps, it is solved.

What I have done is :

I have added a subdivision modifier
[image]

Then I have smoothed the surface. At this time, problems were still present on my mesh. 
[image]

Finally, I have activated auto-smooth option 
[image]

What I get is alright : 
[image]

Thank you for your help guys !